# No script name passed to php-fpm via nginx/FastCGI

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I run a PHP 5.5/5.6 instance over php-fpm without any problems (unix sockets and nginx).

Today I compiled PHP 7 and also started it as a third PHP instance. While requests get served fine with the PHP 5.5/5.6 instances for the PHP 7 instance I get:

> WARNING: pid 2582, fpm_request_check_timed_out(), line 277: [pool www0] child 2813, script '' (request: " ") execution timed out (120.018160 sec), terminating

in my php-fpm log file and

> [error] 1889#0: *4 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.20, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php70-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.21"

in my nginx error log file.

I use `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name` which also works for the PHP 5.6 instance. Although the script filename for PHP 7 seems to be empty. I'm requesting a script `/info.php`.

Is there any difference between using PHP 5.x and 7.0 with php-fpm?

---

**UPDATE**

At least I'm not the only one who is facing those problems as it seems. I opened a bug report here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69850

There is also a very similar (probably identical) bug already reported over here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69875 (thx to @crypticツ)

**UPDATE 2**

**[Try the newest alpha2](https://github.com/php/php-src/releases/tag/php-7.0.0alpha2)**. The bug is fixed there. Unix sockets work now like a charm again.

Comment: Downvote? For what reason?

Comment: who knows ... afiac your question is perfectly valid and in scope for this forum. You are paving the way for my 'real soon now' stack upgrade :)

Comment: Is $fastcgi_script_name empty at php arrival? whats in SCRIPT_FILENAME? does php7 have access to the socket? what happens via tcp?

Comment: Same happens to FastCGI over TCP. The socket can be accessed by PHP7. How can I check that with the empty `$fastcgi_script_name`?

Comment: I'm getting the same/similar issue. Mine could be related to this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69875 Are you also getting the other errors?

Comment: @crypticツ yep that looks exactly like my log.

Comment: When I do a fresh restart of php-fpm I get no errors in log. But the moment I make one PHP request to any pool it begins to go into a death spiral and start logging errors non-stop for that pool. @TiMESPLiNTER read this https://groups.drupal.org/node/229898#comment-1091368 doing that I was able to get rid of the `you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers` errors, but the rest of the errors still occur.

Comment: @crypticツ yes I played around with those config parameteres. But the empty script error stays the same. And to be honest: why do I have to increase those limits for one single request each 5 minutes. This should be handled fine with the fpm default settings. So maybe those two things are related or at least they are 2 separate bugs.

Comment: It's good that you are testing Php7 but it's in Alpha stage right now. I've heard there are breakages in some of the SAPI's and some are being discarded. If this were a php-fpm config issue, I'd think it should be on ServerFault and if it were a php language programming issue it should be here. As it is, "stuff isn't working correctly yet on this alpha software" I think it belongs in PHP's bug reporter, only. Despite this, I'm not down voting. Find the maintainer of and contact him or her.

Comment: @Rob_vH as mentioned already in my initial post I have opened a bug report at php.net. You're right about that and so I linked the bug report in my question but I let the question open because as you see there seem to be some people who end up here with the very same problem.

Comment: php7-fpm is showing a blank request, while the nginx log is showing /info.php as the request. Something seems fishy in the proxy connection or php-fpm's config. Also, does it work properly when the other two fpm instances are not running?

Comment: Via: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69850 it's been confirmed by a PHP dev that UDS (Unix Domain Sockets) is broken in PHP7. So now we just wait for it to be fixed in next tagged release. This question can be closed or deleted after that since it would no longer be effecting people who get the latest test release.

Comment: `Plus1` I am facing this issue too!

Comment: I just tried this under PHP 7.0.0-alpha2 and the problem seems to no longer be there.

Comment: @crypticツ Yep. I confirm. It's fixed in alpha2 :-D.

Comment: I'd leave this post up until alpha2 is officially released/announced, anyone testing should be using it instead of alpha1. I'm really glad it magically fixed itself, because there is no mention of a bugfix in the changelog.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this can be considered as answer, but at this moment, when I am writing this answer, the bug you have raised has been deemed **confirmed** by the PHP Team:

```
[2015-06-23 12:47 UTC] remi@php.net
I confirm
PHP 5.6.10 works
PHP 7.0.0-dev (Jun 17 2015)
- network socket: OK.
- UDS: broken
```

**Update:** I just saw that you are aware of the same too!